# How to store the visit user ip address in salesforce

Tags: force.com

I have developed a simple registration page and given this page access to users through a force.com site. How can I store the visiting user's IP address in Salesforce?

Answer (score 6):

Following may help:

```
String clientIP = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('True-Client-IP');
if(clientIP == null || clientIP == ''){
    clientIP = ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('X-Salesforce-SIP');
}
```

Comment: Hi San Tosh, Thank You for your help, it's woking fine.  i have another question based on IP Address how we can get the Address (Street, City ,Country) information. Please help on this.                                                           i Relly Appreciate your help

Comment: This can only be done by external API. you could use latitude and longitude for finding this. Pass the data to Google Maps API and it returns the address.