# Figure out subscriber's IP address

Tags: javascript, gdpr

According to the GDPR (apparently) when a contact agrees to get marketing information, this consent has to be logged together with the contact's IP address.

How can this address be obtained? The system _Click view does not contain this information.

Whether incorporating some client-side JavaScript evaluating the IP address code into the LinkContent is the only possibility?

The new release of SF MC has to have some means to achieve this.

Any pointers and code samples will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is more *where* your data flows in to your Marketing Cloud, that is the place that should collect details such as the IP address.

For an example, you collect Leads from external web page. Or a Mobile App where users can sign up for an account, or backend system that registers customers and feeds them to CRM.

Think of the entry source where you get your customers into your Marketing Cloud.

Comment: OK, I'll simplify: by now, with the GDPR coming, and lots of SF MC customers who do not even know what a backend is (and do not care about any websites), there has to be a standard consent email template providing the IP address where the "subscribe" button was clicked. Or any other simple channel where they can get this IP adddress from, like the system's _Click view.

Comment: Otherwise, 99.99% SF MC users/customers are in immediate gross GDPR violation. Besides, those who have not yet recorded the consent IP addresses will need to erase their contacts DBs without consent IPs.

Comment: That's absolutely correct, any consents collected without proof where and how it was collected becomes data for erasure. 

The only option for such customers is to re-collect the consent right now, before the GDPR kicks in. Several clients of ours launched their Consent Collection campaigns in early January to re-collect any consents that were questionably obtained.

Comment: Answering my own question, but there should be some SF MC boilerplate solution for this. Please share! It suffices to embed into an email sent to a contact a REST call as described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/391979/how-to-get-clients-ip-address-using-javascript-only and attach the IP returned to the link, which will later be fetched from _Click's LinkContent field.

Comment: Getting ClientIP from JavaScript has it's set of challenges. For example, users with privacy plugins of ad-blockers will block the domains of the db-ip.com, geobytes.com, etc. The best bet is to get this info from the server. For example, here is how to do this in Apex, although I'm not totally sure how MC works here and whether is going to help: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/91930/796